# add animation to a part of spannable string builder

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I have a text and i want to display an animation instead of some words of text.

```
    SpannableStringBuilder ss = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    String[] words = target.getLine1().split("\\s");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        ss.append(" ");

        if (target.getAdvanced().contains(words[i])){

            ss.append(" ", new ImageSpan(context, drawable.ic_baseline_remove_circle_24), 0);

        }else{

            ss.append(words[i]);
        }
    }

    holder.tv_line.append(ss);
```

Comment: Hi! Could you give some more detail about how exactly you want the text animated as well as describing a bit about what your current code already does?

Comment: I have a text and some of its words should be hidden. so I used spannable string builder and instead of those words I placed image span. now I want to animate this image span.